# Angular2 with ASP.NET Core CORS issues when sending POST request

Tags: asp.net, angular

Having issues when sending a POST request via my Angular 2 service to an ASP.NET Core API. I am currently getting a HTTP 500 error:

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:51014/api/sites. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500."

I am not getting this error on GET requests and as far as I can see I have CORS setup correctly server side?

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...

        services.AddCors();
        services.AddMvc();            

        ....
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        ...

        app.UseCors(builder =>
            builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod());

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

    }
```

**SitesContoller.cs**

```
// POST: api/Sites
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostSite([FromBody] Site site)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        _context.Sites.Add(site);
        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (SiteExists(site.Id))
            {
                return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status409Conflict);
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return CreatedAtAction("GetSite", new { id = site.Id }, site);
    }
```

My Angular 2 service:

**site.service.ts snippet**

```
public createSite(site: Site): Observable<Site> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let body = JSON.stringify(site);

    return this.http
        .post(this.apiUrl + 'sites', { body }, options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

Comment: Did you find the answer to this? Seems like a bug in ASP.NET Core...?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the EnableCors attribute to your SiteController class. Like this

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://<SOME_SITE>", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class SiteController {
.....
}
```

refer to this [link](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Cannot tell from you code snippet this is the case, bit you do need it.